# Lightweight GUI-OS to show webbrowser with modern webpage

Tags: operating-systems, gui, web-browsers

Hi I'm looking for an OS that is capable to show an webbrowser (in fullscreen) on an raspberry pi 2 (no other GUI elements are required/necessary).

The website is just one page using html, jquerry and some other "modern" libraries. For this I'm looking for a lightweight OS that doesn't need the overhead of a "regular" raspberry pi OS (e.g. noobs).

Is there a OS that supports this or is made for this specific use case?

So to be clear. Its **not** about hosting an webpage it's about displaying the webpage on a screen using the raspberry pi.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for ([FullPage OS](https://github.com/guysoft/FullPageOS)). I never used it before but looking at some of the feedbacks it had, I'm guessing it's fine, but please note **Do it at your own risk, and I do not take responsibility if anything goes wrong**

[image]

Not sure if light weight, since it is chrome and chrome tends to be a little resource heavy. I would also suggest using [Raspbian OS](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) or maybe even [MATE](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/), they are fast and reliable on the Raspberry Pi.